# Fill in a textfield value via autocomplete jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" placeholder=" " name="firstName" id="firstName" required="" class="gl-input__field gl-input__field--empty gl-input__field--with-icon" maxlength="33" autocomplete="on" data-auto-id="shippingAddress-firstName" value="">
```

How would I automatically fill in this value using autocomplete? I tried googling but I am honestly confused and I am a full stack developer but I don't do web development unless I absolutely need too.

I figured out this much;

```
$('#firstName').autocomplete("Bob")
```

but instead of "Bob" its supposed to be a method and I don't know what to put?

Can I do autocomplete for each id separately or do I gotta do all at once?

Since 'autocomplete' is the actual ID itself, how would i do this?

Thanks.

P.S. I also am injecting "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" into the page if that matters.

I tried

```
$("#firstName").autocomplete({value: "Bob"}).trigger("change");
```

but no text appears in the textbox!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method as follows

```
$( "#firstName" ).autocomplete({source: firstNameList()});
```

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#firstName" ).autocomplete({source: [firstNameList()]});    
    $( "#lastName" ).autocomplete({source: [lastNameList()]});

 });
  
 function firstNameList() {
    return "firstnames";
}
function lastNameList() {
    return "lastname";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="firstName" id="firstName" required="" class="gl-input__field gl-input__field--empty gl-input__field--with-icon" maxlength="33" autocomplete="on" data-auto-id="shippingAddress-firstName" value="">
  <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="lastName" id="lastName" required="" class="gl-input__field gl-input__field--empty gl-input__field--with-icon" maxlength="33" autocomplete="on" data-auto-id="shippingAddress-lastName" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: but I just want one value in the textbox text value? Can I do without declaring an additional function and all those values...I just want 1 value to be in the textbox value?

Comment: isn't this supposed to automatically put the value in the textbox? This makes it so I have to type "f" in the textbox to see "firstnames", which I do not want.